# Can't make my program search more than 1 line in text file`?

Tags: c++

im tryng to make a small database for a school project, but i have runned into som problems.

My program is working fine it can add a new subject to my database, but my problem is, when i search for anything else than stands on the first line of my txt document, it won't work.

Example:

If i add, toby and sara to the list, it will only be able to find toby.

What can i do ?

P.s: I know that there are many wrong things, in this code sorry.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

void searchname();
void add();
void exit();

int main()
{
    system("color 0E");
    std::cout << "Velkommen til den store database over spillet World og Warcraft" << "\n";
    std::cout << "Tryk venligst på en vilkårlig tast for at fortsaette" << "\n";
    std::cout << "" << "\n";
    std::cin.get();

    cout << "Vaelg venligst et emne (skriv nummer fra emne liste):" << "\n";
    int valg;
    cout << "1. Add" << "\n";
    cout << "2. Shearch" << "\n";
    cout << "3. List of all Races and Classes" << "\n";
    cout << "4. Afslut program" << "\n";
    cin >> valg;
    system ("CLS");


    switch (valg) {
    case 1:
        add();
        break;
    case 2:
        searchname();
        break;
    case 3:

        int a = 0;
        cout << "Classes" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Warrior" << endl;
        cout << "Paladin" << endl;
        cout << "Hunter" << endl;
        cout << "Rogue" << endl;
        cout << "Priest" << endl;
        cout << "Death Knight" << endl;
        cout << "Shaman" << endl;
        cout << "Mage" << endl;
        cout << "Warlock" << endl;
        cout << "Monk" << endl;
        cout << "Druid" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Races" << endl;
        cout << "Alliance       Horde" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Pandaren       Pandaren" << endl;
        cout << "Worgen         Goblin" << endl;
        cout << "Draenei            Blood Elf" << endl;
        cout << "Dwarf          Orc" << endl;
        cout << "Gnome          Tauraen" << endl;
        cout << "Human          Troll" << endl;
        cout << "Night Elf      Undead" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "Want to search info? write 1" << endl;
        cout << "Want to return to menu? write 2" << endl;
        cin >> a;


        while (1) {
            if (a == 1) {
                searchname();
                system("pause");
            }
            else {
                system("CLS");
                main();
            }
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    main();
}

void add() {
    string name;
    string faction;
    string classe;
    string race;
    string info;
    ofstream wowdatabase("wowdatabase.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Add a race or class" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of the race or class (only small letters!)" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter Race (Type -, if writen in name section)" << endl;
    cin >> race;

    cout << "Enter Class (Type -, if writen in name section)" << endl;
    cin >> classe;


    cout << "Enter faction" << endl;
    cin >> faction;

    cout << "Enter the information" << endl;
    cin >> info;

    wowdatabase << name << ' ' << race << ' ' << classe << ' ' << faction << ' ' << info << endl;
    wowdatabase.close();
    system("CLS");
    main();
}



void searchname() {


    ifstream charecter("wowdatabase.txt");
    string name;
    string find;
    string faction;
    string classe;
    string race;
    string info;
    int i = 0;


    system("CLS");
    cout << "Search for a race or class" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter name:";
    cin >> find;



    while (charecter >> name >> faction >> classe >> race >> info ) {

        if (find == name) {

            system("CLS");
            cout << "Charecter found" << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------------------------------------    --" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "Name of race/class: " << name << endl;
            cout << "Race: " << race << endl;
            cout << "Class: " << classe << endl;
            cout << "Faction: " << faction << endl;
            cout << "Info: " << ' ' << info << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "Press enter to return to menu" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            main();




        }

        if (!(find == name )) {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Charecter found" << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "No charecter was found with that name, sure you got it right?" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "Press enter to return to menu" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            main();
        }

    }



    system("pause");
    cin.get();
    main();

}

void search() {

    int valg2;
    system("CLS");

    cout << "1. Search by name" << endl;
    cin >> valg2;

    switch (valg2) {
    case 1:
        searchname();
        break;

    }

}


void exit() {
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and fix the bugs one by one. Add logging or use a debugger if necessary.

Here's one to help you along:

This block of code:

```
   if (!(find == name )) {
   ...
```

Should be outside this block of code:

```
   while (charecter >> name >> faction >> classe >> race >> info ) {
```

You put it inside the block, causing the function to call `main` (why do you do that at all?!) if the first line doesn't match.

Also, your logic is horribly broken everywhere. For example:

```
case 2:
    searchname();
    break;
```

The `searchname` function never returns. So what is this `break` doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
wowdatabase << name << ' ' << race << ' ' << classe << ' ' << faction << ' ' << info << endl;
```

pushes a single string ending in a newline.

```
while (charecter >> name >> faction >> classe >> race >> info ) {
```

The first string ending in a newline goes to name, the second goes to faction, the third goes to classe, and so on.

You can fix this by:

```
wowdatabase << name << endl << faction << endl << classe << endl << race << endl << info << endl;
```